# Como comparar dados importados no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde,

Estou migrando meu banco de dados para um novo, com isso gerei um script de insert dos dados pegando estes dados do antigo banco. Porem, algumas tabelas notei que não estão sendo importados todos os registros da tabela e gostaria de uma forma de comparar estes dois bancos para saber quais tabelas estão com registros a menor do que o banco original. Alguem poderia me orientar?

Answer (score -2):

Roda essa query nos 2 bancos, ele vai te dar o tamanho de cada uma para comparar.

De qualque forma, uma importação dessa deve ser feita com algum ponto de corte caso queira migrar aos poucos. Ou utilize uma ferramenta para fazer isso (DTS ou SQLAzureMW)

```
SELECT
OBJECT_NAME(object_id) As Tabela, 
Rows As Linhas,
SUM(Total_Pages * 8) As Reservado,
SUM(CASE WHEN Index_ID > 1 THEN 0 ELSE Data_Pages * 8 END) As Dados,
    SUM(Used_Pages * 8) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Index_ID > 1 THEN 0 ELSE Data_Pages * 8 END) As Indice,
SUM((Total_Pages - Used_Pages) * 8) As NaoUtilizado 
FROM sys.partitions As P
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units As A ON P.hobt_id = A.container_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) NOT LIKE 'sys%'
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id), Rows
ORDER BY Dados DESC
```

Comment: Obrigado!! Irei testar